# GET Call with parameters in ajax

Tags: json, jquery, cordova

This should be an easy one. but its not going well for me.

Just for the heads up, even though i dont believe it has an influence: i am doing this in phonegap.

I've created a wcf service that connects my app to the database.
Instead of connecting to the wcf service directly, i've made a simple html page that takes the GET parameters from the url, and connects to the database with those values

Alright, i've put a test file called ajax_info.html on the site, and my scripts are working fine. But when i put the url above in, it wont do anything. i connected my phone to fiddler, and absolutely nothing happens...

Here's my script (credits to wc3schools).

```
   function loadXMLDoc()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      var user= "something";
      var pass= "something";
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/wcf/site.html"+"?user="+user+"&pass="+pass,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

This code is not working at all:

```
function login(){
       $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/wcf/site.html",
            data: {"user":"something", "pass":"something"},
            // processData: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    },
            error: function (msg) {

                       $.each(msg, function() {
                            $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                                alert(v);
                            });
                        });
                    }

  });
    }
```

Comment: You should say and add a tag for what Javascript framework you are using.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to this. What do you mean?
I have this in my index.html:
`<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I meant a StackOverflow tag, which is now here.  I don't know jQuery so I cannot try to help you with its AJAX implementation--the same question in Dojo, I could help.  Tagging your tools in the question will help attract people able to answer :-)

Comment: You are right. Didnt think about it being about javascript as well. But the issue have been resolved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$.get("http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/wcf/site.html", {"user":"something", "pass":"something"}, function() {
    alert("success");
  })
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Greetings.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing and stupid of me. i will accept your answer because it works.
But the issue were that the jquery reference wasnt there. So my scripts worked as well.